# c# - WebBrowser - Reusing Control

Tags: c#, .net

I am no expert in c#, so please bear with me. I am tasked with creating an application that is pretty straight-forward. I am writing some code that interfaces with a 3rd party IVR API. Once a user is logged into that API, a handler is created that watches that user's telephone queue for a phone call. This portion of the code works flawlessly... Phone call comes in, handler event fires.

When the user logs in, I also pop two Internet Explorer windows (both new windows). When the phone call event handler fires, I simply need to Navigate one window to a new URL, and execute some javascript to the other window. So, I old-schooled my way through using SHDocVw InternetExlorer objects, and everything worked great. Then I turned UAC on to the default level (project requirement), and it more or less broke my project as I could no longer gain control over the InternetExplorer object.

Through research, it appears a WebBrowser is the way to go with UAC (please someone correct me if I am wrong). So that is where I am today. I am having trouble maintaining control of the WebBrowser object after I create it.

Here is how I create it:

```
var th = new Thread(() =>
            {

                WebBrowser BSWebBrowser = new WebBrowser();
                BSWebBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(BSDocumentCompleted); 
                BSWebBrowser.Visible = true;
                var URL = SomeURL;
                BSWebBrowser.Navigate(URL);

                Application.Run();
            });
            th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            th.Start();
```

And then I run the DocumentCompleted code to hopefully set the WebBrowser to something not null:

```
        private void BSDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser BSWebBrowser = sender as WebBrowser;
        if (BSWebBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Browser Not Ready!");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Browser Ready!");
        }
    }
```

When I debug on the BSCocumentCompleted code above, the BSWebBrowser is not null which is good. Now when a phone call comes in, I try to Navigate the BSWebBrowser to another URL. I call:

```
BSWebBrowser.Navigate("somenewURL");
```

I have a couple problems...

1. The above code does not pop Internet Explorer window visually. If I add true after the URL in the navigate, to open a new window, my documentcompleted never fires and I can not maintain control over the WebBrowser.
2. If I run the above code as "windowless" (which I don't really want to do, but am just doing to try to figure out how to maintain control over WebBrowser), I get the following error: "Unable to get the window handle for the 'WebBrowser' control. Windowless ActiveX controls are not supported.

Anyone have any ideas on how to either use WebBrowser correctly, or use another UAC compliant way to navigate an Internet Explorer window more than once?

I humbly appreciate any help.

Comment: I can work around this dilemma by the dirty trick of looping through ShellWindows and looking up the document.title and document.url... Then taking control of the object and forcing a Navigation... I still feel like there is an obvious way to maintain control of a WebBrowser object and reference that object later, even if it was created on a different thread. Maybe I'm way off here...